# ProgressBar is not stopping

Tags: android, progress-bar

My app contained a login button and whenever that button is pressed, I want some Progress Bar to show up so that the user knows there is something happening. I've Progress Bar in XML but now i don't know how to set it in code. Please guide me where to put lines as when I press login button a Progress Bar shown up, here is my code

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout_password"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:text="login"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout_password"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;
EditText email,password;
Button login;
String url="http://192.168.1.5/Register/login.php" ;

AlertDialog.Builder builder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView=findViewById(R.id.register);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Register.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    email=findViewById(R.id.email);
    password=findViewById(R.id.password);
    login=findViewById(R.id.login);

    builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String user_email=email.getText().toString();
            final String user_password=password.getText().toString();

            if (user_email.equals("")||user_password.equals("")){
                builder.setTitle("Something Went Wrong...");
                dispalyAlert("Enter a valid Email and Password");
            }
            else {
                StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                                try {
                                    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                                    JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                    String code=jsonObject.getString("code");
                                    if (code.equals("login_failed")){
                                        builder.setTitle("Login Error...");
                                        dispalyAlert(jsonObject.getString("message"));
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginSuccess.class);
                                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putString("name",jsonObject.getString("name"));
                                   // bundle.putString("email",jsonObject.getString("email"));
                                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("email",user_email);
                        params.put("password",user_password);
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void dispalyAlert(String message){
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            email.setText("");
            password.setText("");
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this as following. you don't have to add the progressBar in xml.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        TextView textView;
        EditText email,password;
        Button login;
        String url="http://192.168.1.5/Register/login.php" ;

        //To show the progressBar
        private ProgressDialog progress;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //Prepare progressBar
            progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progress.setTitle("Please Wait!!");
            progress.setMessage("Wait!!");
            progress.setCancelable(false);
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

            textView=findViewById(R.id.register);
            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Register.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            email=findViewById(R.id.email);
            password=findViewById(R.id.password);
            login=findViewById(R.id.login);

            builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final String user_email=email.getText().toString();
                    final String user_password=password.getText().toString();

                    if (user_email.equals("")||user_password.equals("")){
                        builder.setTitle("Something Went Wrong...");
                        dispalyAlert("Enter a valid Email and Password");
                    }
                    else {
                        //Show the progressBar
                        progress.show();

                        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                                        //Hide the progressBar
                                        progress.dismiss(); 
                                        try {
                                            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                                            JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                            String code=jsonObject.getString("code");
                                            if (code.equals("login_failed")){
                                                builder.setTitle("Login Error...");
                                                dispalyAlert(jsonObject.getString("message"));
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginSuccess.class);
                                            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                                            bundle.putString("name",jsonObject.getString("name"));
                                           // bundle.putString("email",jsonObject.getString("email"));
                                            intent.putExtras(bundle);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                            }
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                //Hide the progressBar
                                progress.dismiss(); 
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                error.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }){
                            @Override
                            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                                Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
                                params.put("email",user_email);
                                params.put("password",user_password);
                                return params;
                            }
                        };
                        MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void dispalyAlert(String message){
            builder.setMessage(message);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    email.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        }
```

Comment: this is perfectly running but ProgressDialog is deprecated in API level 26 so I've to use  ProgressBar so where to visible this ProgressBar and where to Gone.

Answer (score 0):

You should be set progress bar visible when user click on button:

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final String user_email=email.getText().toString();
        final String user_password=password.getText().toString();
         if (user_email.equals("")||user_password.equals("")){
            builder.setTitle("Something Went Wrong...");
            dispalyAlert("Enter a valid Email and Password");
        }else{  //Right here
            findViewById(R.id.loading).setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
```

You have to set visibility to gone when stop to load :

```
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                String code=jsonObject.getString("code");
                if (code.equals("login_failed")){
                    builder.setTitle("Login Error...");
                    dispalyAlert(jsonObject.getString("message"));
                }
                else {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginSuccess.class);
                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("name",jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    // bundle.putString("email",jsonObject.getString("email"));
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            findViewById(R.id.loading).setVisible(View.GONE); ////Here
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            findViewById(R.id.loading).setVisible(View.GONE); //Here
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: findViewById(R.id.loading).setVisible(View.GONE); above new Response.ErrorListener() { is not accepting